# Environment Variables on Windows for node

Tags: node.js, windows, cygwin, environment-variables

I'm running node on a windows server, through Cygwin, and i need to setup some env variables.
I have to scripts:

./run-linux.sh - to run on linux or mac

```
SBS_API_KEY="ksdjfdsklfjds" \
SBS_AUTH_USERNAME="dkfjsdl" \
SBS_AUTH_PASSWORD="lksdjfsdlfj" \
SBS_S3_KEY="lskdfjsdlkfjdslfj" \
SBS_S3_SECRET="ldfkjdflgjdflgjdf" \
SBS_BITCODIN_KEY="kldfjldsjfsdlfj" \
npm start
```

and ./run-windows - to run on windows

```
set SBS_API_KEY="ksdjhdskfhskdfhshsd" &&
set SBS_AUTH_USERNAME="kdsfkfshdskjf" &&
set SBS_AUTH_PASSWORD="ksdffsdkfhdsk" &&
set SBS_S3_KEY="sdlkfjldskfjdslfjsdl" &&
set SBS_S3_SECRET="sdlkjfdlskfjlsdfj" &&
set SBS_BITCODIN_KEY="kdjshfksdsdkhf" &&
npm start
```

I have tried several possibilities but i can't make node to pick up the Env variables set in ./run-windows when i run it.

What is the proper way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows environment variables, don't try concatenating the settings. Instead simply set them in turn, as follows

```
set SBS_API_KEY="ksdjhdskfhskdfhshsd"
set SBS_AUTH_USERNAME="kdsfkfshdskjf"
set SBS_AUTH_PASSWORD="ksdffsdkfhdsk"
set SBS_S3_KEY="sdlkfjldskfjdslfjsdl"
set SBS_S3_SECRET="sdlkjfdlskfjlsdfj"
set SBS_BITCODIN_KEY="kdjshfksdsdkhf"
```

This works when I set your environment variables on my command line and should work fine in a batch file. BTW I'd expect your run-windows batch file to end with either `.bat` or `.cmd`